# How to loop through blocks of pixels with minimum number of for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, image-processing

I have an image of width * height pixels in which i want to loop through blocks of pixels, say block size of 10 * 10. How can i do this with minimum number of loops?

I have tried by first looping through each column, then through each row and took the starting x and y position from this two outer loops. Then the loop goes from start position of the block and loops till the block size and manipulates the pixels. This consumes four nested loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i+=Block_Size) {

 for (int j = 0; j < Height; j+=Block_Size) {

   for (int x = i; x < i + Block_Size; x++) {

      for (int y = j; y < j + Block_Size; y++) {                     

        //Get pixel values within the block

       }

     }

   }

 }
```

Comment: Well, there isn't really any other way to do it. Four loops is the minimum. If you're concerned about performance or time complexity, having four loops does not mean anything, it's still Θ(n) (with n being the number of pixels) given the way you do it.

Comment: If the loops bother you, use recursion instead.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to discuss your concerns about the four-loop nest, and why you think reducing the number of loops would be to your advantage.

Comment: “This consumes four nested loops“. Don’t worry, there is not a limited supply of loops. We won’t run out of them. Use as many as you need to get your task done. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i do this with minimum number of loops?

You can reduce the number of loops by completely unrolling as many loop levels as you like.  For fixed raster dimensions, you could unroll them all, yielding a (probably lengthy) implementation with zero loops.  For known `Block_Size` you can unroll one or both of the inner loops regardless of whether the overall dimensions are known, yielding as few as two loops remaining.

But why would you consider such a thing?  The question seems to assume that there would be some kind of inherent advantage to reducing the depth of loop nest, but that's not necessarily true, and whatever effect there might be is likely to be small.

I'm inclined to guess that you've studied a bit of computational complexity theory, and taken away the idea that deep loop nests necessarily yield poorly-scaling performance, or even that deep loop nests have inherently poor performance, period.  These are misconceptions, albeit relatively common ones, and they anyway look at the problem backwards.

The primary consideration in how the performance of your loop nest scales is how many times the body of the innermost loop,

> ```
>         //Get pixel values within the block
> ```

, is executed.  You'll have roughly the same performance for any reasonable approach that causes it to be executed exactly once for every pixel in the raster, regardless of how many loops are involved.  With that being the case, code clarity should be your goal, and your original four-loop nest is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this with three loops, but in order to do that you will need to store information about where each block of pixels starts and how many blocks of pixels there are in total!
Independent of that, both the width as well as the height of the image have to be multiples of your `Block_Size`.

Here is how it is possible with three loops:

```
int numberOfBlocks = x;
int pixelBlockStartingPoints[numberOfBlocks] = { startingPoint1, startingPoint2, ... };

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++){
    for(int j = pixelBlockStartingPoints[i]; j < pixelBlockStartingPoint[i] + Block_Size; j++){
        for(int k = pixelBlockStartingPoints[i]; k < pixelBlockStartingPoint[i] + Block_Size; k++){
            // Get Pixel-Data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will try it out

Comment: Even with the supporting array, how does this provide for processing blocks that do not contain the main diagonal of the raster?  I take `j` and `k` to be meant for the pixel coordinates, and in every case they have the same starting values as each other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, `j` and `k` are temporary for every block of pixels, they store the width and the height of a pixel relative to the Pixel-Block-Starting-Point. Like I said, in order for this to work you need to know the locations of all blocks and where the first pixel in that block is located (this is stored in the `pixelBlockStartingPoints`-Array

Comment: From what I can see, then, your `j` and `k` are not analogous to the OP's `x` and `y`, which leaves this answer a bit misleading to my eye.  The specifics of the computation of `x` and `y` from `j` and `k` will depend on how the single starting point values are computed from 2D raster coordinates, but will likely depend on the dimensions of the raster.  And of course, there's no reason to think that this will have better performance characteristics than the 4-loop nest, so it is also misleading to whatever extent it presents an appearance to the contrary.